# Проверить данные в объекте PHP на соответствие

Tags: php, json, phalcon

Пишу приложение авторизации на PHP API (Phalcon).
Столкнулся с следующей задачей, при регистрации пользователя на сервере принимаются следующий запрос от клиента:

```
{
  "first_name": "Человек",
  "last_name": "Человечище",
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "password": "12345678"
}
```

На стороне сервера запрос принимается `$data = $this->request->getJsonRawBody();` и создается массив объектов:
stdClass Object

```
(
    [first_name] => Человек
    [last_name] => Человечище
    [email] => test@test.com
    [password] => 12345678
)
```

Все бы не чего но вот задача, надо чтобы приходящие ключи соответствовали тому что я пропишу и нельзя было нечего левого добавить в запрос.

Если я посылаю запрос, или не добавляю какого-то ключа:

```
{
    "first_name": "Человек",
    "last_name": "Человечище",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "ЛИШНИЙ КЛЮЧ": "ЛИШНЕЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"
}
```

То сервер не должен пропустить запрос.
Как это можно реализовать?

Спасибо!

Comment: А валидация для кого придумана?) https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/ru-ru/validation

Comment: Тоже как вариант =) Только играюсь с Phalcon, еще не во все вник... Спасибо!

Comment: Сейчас проверил вариант с валидацией Confirmation. Массивы он не сравнивает=(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень много людей плюются и гадят сторону PHP, но всё-же решений из коробки там более чем достаточно. Ответ на твою задачу лежит в `intersect` функциях

```php
<?php

$values = [
    "first_name" => "Человек",
    "last_name" => "Человечище",
    "email" =>  "test@test.com",
    "password" => "12345678",
    "ЛИШНИЙ КЛЮЧ" => "ЛИШНЕЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"
];

$validator = [
    "first_name" => 1,
    "last_name" => 1,
    "password" => 1,
    "email" => 1,
];


$res = array_intersect_key($values, $validator);
print_r($res);
```

Результат выполнения, выявленные ключи из 2го массива, разрешены к значениям первого. Какие значения у 2го массива, без разницы.

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Человек
    [last_name] => Человечище
    [email] => test@test.com
    [password] => 12345678
)
```

Comment: А для чего тут в маске значение "1"? Убрал значение и проверка не прошла

Comment: Для того чтобы сравнивать __ключи__, а не значения.

Answer (score 1):

Заранее создаём массив, где указываем все "подабающие" ключи. Так называемый "белый список".

```
['first_name', 'last_name, 'email', 'password']
```

затем из принятого массива берём ключи **[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-keys.php)**

Затем сравниваем два массива через  **[array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php)**. Если есть разница - значит что-то не то.